# if $\sum a_n^2$ is convergent then $b_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\cdot\sqrt{i}$ is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I have no idea how to approach the following problem:

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Given that $\sum a_n^2$ is convergent prove that the sequence  $b_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \cdot \sqrt{i}$ is bounded.

I just know that $\lim a_n^2=0$ but not sure if that helps. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\sqrt{i}\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\right)^{1/2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2}\right)^{1/2}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{align*}
But $\sqrt{n(n+1)}/n\leq\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: why on earth did I not think about that! Thanks